# RenderScript set element of rs_allocation in pre-API 18

Tags: android, renderscript

From API 18 there is available function **rsSetElementAt** to set cell of rs_allocation. But how is this possible in APIs lower than 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible prior to API 18.  You could sample `Allocation`s which was set for your kernel then apply any changes to the output of your kernel.  But, there was no API prior to API 18 to set a cell within an `Allocation`.